# two div display inline

Tags: html, css

I am hustling with a view of css that one div should be next to each other and not down of the 1st div

what i want to achieve is in this picture that i made

[image]

i am working with a plunker

http://jsfiddle.net/ao98u6vy/1/

but not able to solve it

```
see my image and plunker
```

Comment: add `display: flex;` to parent div (#wrapper)

Answer (score 1):

Are you able to use css Flexbox, this is very well supported in all modern browsers.  If you  are then you could just set the display of your wrapper container to flex as below.

```
#wrapper {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    display: flex;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use display flex on the parent div having id `wrapper`

```
#wrapper {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  display: flex;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing it is setting `display: flex;` to the wrapper:

```
#wrapper {
  display: flex;
}
```

Or following your method but adding `float` and `box-sizing` props

```
body {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
* {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}
#wrapper {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
#div1 {
  display: inline-block;
  width:20px;
  height:20px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
#div2 {
  display: inline-block;
  width: calc(100% - 20px);
  border: 1px solid green;
  float: right;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code should works.

```
 #wrapper {
      border: 1px solid blue;
 }
#div1 {
    display: inline-block;
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    vertical-align:top;
}
#div2 {
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 95%;
    border: 1px solid green;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#wrapper {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    display: flex;
}
```